# Set Terminal tabs to show open file name

Tags: macos, emacs, tabs, terminal

I code using Terminal.app (2.3), which can set each tab to be the current command running in the given shell.  Since most of the time my different tabs are different files open in emacs, is there a way to have the tab title set to the name of the file?

Comment: invoking `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "insert text here"; echo -ne "\007"'` in your .bash_profile will change your title to the text in side the double quotes when ever you open a login terminal. You could insert a Variable in there. I have ${PWD} so it displays my current path. Hopefully that puts you in the direction you're wanting

Comment: Thanks @ClydeByrdIII but it doesn't sound like that would be entirely appropriate for my particular design.

Comment: Ah yeah, your looking for only when emacs is open sorry. You could alias emacs to invoke the export on calling emacs. and take the file name as a variable. and returning wouldn't be too bad either.